# RAISERROR And ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to use the sp as following in asp.net page.

How can I show the Error messages in sp into asp.net ?

Any DAL property sample to do the task in asp.net by calling the sp ?

Is there any conflict between using RAISERROR and ROLLBACK TRANSACTION both in sp ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cyrex_ChangeUsername]

@oldName nvarchar(128),
@newName nvarchar(128)

AS

declare @error_var int, @rowcount_var int
declare @newNameCount int

begin transaction

 select @newNameCount = count(*)
  from Users
  where Username = ltrim(rtrim(@newName))
 if @newNameCount > 0 
 begin
  RAISERROR('Username already exists. @newName=%s', 10, 1, @newName) 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  RETURN
 end

 update Users
 set Username = ltrim(rtrim(@newName))
 where Username = ltrim(rtrim(@oldName))

 SELECT @error_var = @@ERROR, @rowcount_var = @@ROWCOUNT
 IF @rowcount_var <> 1 OR @error_var <> 0
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Could not Update User.Username. @oldName=%s', 10, 1, @oldName) 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  RETURN
 END


 update aspnet_Users
 set 
  Username = @newName,
  LoweredUserName = LOWER(@newName)
 where LoweredUserName = LOWER(@oldName)

 SELECT @error_var = @@ERROR, @rowcount_var = @@ROWCOUNT
 IF @rowcount_var <> 1 OR @error_var <> 0
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Could not Update aspnet_Users.Username. @oldName=%s', 10, 1, @oldName) 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  RETURN
 END

Commit transaction
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using [severity level 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) on your Raiserror.

Severities of 10 and less do not allow an Exception to be trapped in your .NET code.

In your proc, if these conditions are errors, would recommend that you increase the severity so that an exception can be caught in .NET.

Severities less than 10 can be detected by subscribing the [InfoMessage event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) on the Connection - an example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thx for ur help. I have another question . I just want to know your idea about sending back the errors through sql to asp.net.Is the task heavy duty for sql server and Its gonna reduce the performance of sql and network ? Or Insted of using error handling in sql do the same process in BLL ?

Comment: The tendency nowadays seems to be to go for business logic in a BLL or similar code concern - especially with technologies such as LINQ2SQL and EF, the lines of code needed to implement rules such as yours will be less than doing this in a SPROC. However, there are plenty of systems still out there using logic in SPROCs (sometimes referred to as 2.5 tier architecture) - so if you already have most of your system in SPROCs, I would leave it be. If you do however choose the BLL route, you might consider using .NET TransactionScopes to manage your transactions.